# libgdx : Playing short loops as music

Tags: libgdx, lwjgl

As far as I know , for background music , we should use a Music instance as it streams from disk and does not eats up memory. But it on the same time is a little slower than sound playback (am I right?)

Now in my game I have a music as such , but I also have rain happening all around . For that I am going to loop a 6 second rain noise . Now What should I do ? Should I play it as a second music or loop it as a sound ?????

Comment: Sound is more efficient for small repetive sound effects. Music is for background music.

Answer (score 0):

In the libgdx tutorial there is an article about a "simple game", in which you move a bucket to catch raindrops. There is a background rain music that is a Music.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game

What i have learned from libgdx so far, is that you will waste a lot of time inventing a wheel, especially if it was already implemented by someone much more experienced, and also it is properly documented.